# How do I get two menu options with dropdowns next to each other in an Android layout file?

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to get a menu layout where I have 2 icons next to each other which both have dropdown options. Currently it's being annoying and putting all the items in the default option menu like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0TIV.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:title="@string/menu_sort"
        android:id="@+id/menu_sort"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_sort_24">

        <item android:title="Distance"/>
        <item android:title="Salary"/>
        <item android:title="Date Posted"/>


    </item>

    <item
        android:title="@string/menu_filter"
        android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_filter_list_24">

        <item android:title="Freelance"/>
        <item android:title="Zero Hour"/>
        <item android:title="Part Term"/>
        <item android:title="Internship"/>

    </item>
 

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help....

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="@string/menu_sort"
        android:id="@+id/menu_sort"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_sort_24">
<menu>
        <item android:title="Distance"/>
        <item android:title="Salary"/>
        <item android:title="Date Posted"/>
</menu>

    </item>
    <item
        android:title="@string/menu_filter"
        android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_filter_list_24">
<menu>
        <item android:title="Freelance"/>
        <item android:title="Zero Hour"/>
        <item android:title="Part Term"/>
        <item android:title="Internship"/>
</menu>
    </item>
 
</menu>
```

You add `<menu></menu>` inside an item and add submenu items there....